# How to package brew binaries for multiple versions of Mac OS

Tags: macos, deployment, package, homebrew

I often have use for software that requires compilation, on machines that don't have developer tools installed. Today I found something that I thought would simplify my life. [Brew-pkg](https://github.com/timsutton/brew-pkg) allows you to create installer packages of things that you already have installed on your system. I took it for a test spin by creating a tmux installer package. Before I knew it I had a an installer. What's more, it worked on a handful of test computers. So I went ahead and distributed the packaged to a number of other computers including some Mac OS 10.6 machines. Sadly, on these machines, tmux just reports `Illegal instruction` and then stops.

So, my question is twofold.
Is there something I don't understand about how binaries work that explains this behavior?

How can I create pkg installers that install and work on various Mac OS versions?

Confusedly,
Cory